# Where to place html files required for this the TreeDemo.java program

Tags: java, html, jtree

How do I run the JTree.demo at "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html". It requires some html files which I managed to improvise. However, the program says it cant find the html files. My guess is that may be I placed them in the wrong directory. Where am I supposed to place them? I had placed them in the root directory of the project!

Comment: Your code or a screenshot of your project folder?

Comment: Never mind, i have discovered that they are supposed to be placed in the same directory as the class files.Still, thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the file any where you want as long as you give the path to the file correctly in the program.

e.g
If you put the file in the project folder it will be easy to give relative path.

If you put the file outside the project folder, use absolute path to the file rather than relative path. It would be more convenient

Comment: Great answer! You might aswell include code snippets if you want to answer like that.

Comment: Thilina you are right!   Thanks for the help, I also first placed them in the project folder.  However, I have discovered why the program doesn't see the files. it is because of the "getClass().getResource()" calling which requires the files to be in the directory containing the class files. Thanks